# Jade nested element not wrap around children

Tags: pug

I'm hoping I'm just missing something simple here.

I'm building a drop-down menu in Jade and the basic structure is this:

**JADE**

```
ul
  li: a(href="example.html")
    ul
      li
```

**HTML Output**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="example.html">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
      </ul></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would like the anchor tag to close right away however and not wrap around the children that are indented.

**Desired HTML Output** (key attention to the anchor tag)

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="example.html"></a>
      <ul>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the anchor on its own line and it will remedy it:

```
ul
  li 
    a(href="example.html")
    ul
      li
```

Outputs:

```
<ul>
  <li> <a href="example.html"></a>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good gosh I knew it had to be something easy like that. Thx duders.